# asp.net databound images don't show up

Tags: asp.net, image, listview, data-binding

I have a listView with a picture column that has a databind to the column in the database. My database column is just type nvarchar and I just have the image path listed in the database column. So the problem comes when I run the debugger, there are 5 different columns that come up in the listview. Two of these columns are displaying the pictures correctly, two of them are only showing the actual path from the database and one of them is showing the image error picture. I have looked over them again and again and the path appears to be correct for all of them. It is working correctly for two of them but why not the others?

Comment: Show your GridView markup, show the data in the database, and explain which columns aren't working.

Comment: I found my solution for the ones that were only showing the path and not the actual image. ListView has an alternatingItemTemplate that I did not notice still had the picture as a label and not an image control. I just need to debug the error with one of the images now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at view source when debugging in browser. The one showing picture error is probably mapped to a wrong path that is not relevant to the server or inaccessible by the server.Remember that you are telling browser where to look for the source. So if image file is located on server's drive C in Images folder and you cupply path as C:\Images the browser will look for that file on client's computer drive C:|.

Comment: Still having trouble with the one image error, the path looks fine. I did manage to fix the others just showing the path and not the actual image. ListView has an alternatingItemTemplate that I did not notice still had the picture as a label and not an image control.

Comment: And when I copy the image address in the browser and past it in the browser it is the correct path and it is the correct format.

Comment: @user3841709  - you need to show db table sample, markup and source as seen in browser.

Comment: I fixed it. There was a typo that was very difficult to spot. Thanks.